# Group data in monthly report using start date and end date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have a table called `tours` in which I have following fields

```
tourId, tourStartDate, tourEndDate , tourDetail ,deptCode,targetYear, and officerName
```

Now i want to summarize my data into months 
so result table should look like by following schema

```
declare @temp table (
  id int identity(1,1) not null,
  officerName, 
  jan int ,feb int,
  march int,april int, 
  may int,
  june int ,
  july int, 
  aug int,
  sep int, 
  oct int, 
  nov int, 
  dec int
);
select * from  @temp
```

I tried with `with cte` to traverse each row and using case to insert in temporary table but its not look like good solution so any clue or guide really help me a lot.

**count of tours done by officer in that month will appear in month column as value**

**EDITED**

A tour with starting date in jan and ending date in some other month, say feb then its value will appear in both month

Comment: A tour with starting date in jan and ending date in some other month, say feb....should it be counted in jan or feb?

Comment: it will appear in both month   ... thanks

Comment: So what if a tour starts in december 2009 and ends in february 2011?

Comment: this data will appear for a year only ... @targetyear is use in where clause ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it appear in both months, [UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) the query parts of (1) by start date (2) by end date, if end is in a different month.  And to compare months, use [MONTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) to take the month of a date.

To get the column names as months, use [DateName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx)(Month, ). To make it consistent, use only the first 3 characters using [LEFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx).

To turn rows into columns, use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
SELECT officerName, Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec
FROM (
    select LEFT(datename(month,tourStartDate),3) mon, officerName
    from tbl
    union all
    select LEFT(datename(month,tourEndDate),3) mon, officerName
    from tbl
    where month(tourStartDate) != month(tourEndDate)
) P
PIVOT (COUNT(mon) for mon in (Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec)) PV
```

Comment: For the first line, `SELECT officerName, Jan as January, Feb as Februaro, ...`

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a `pivot`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Something like

```
select *
from  (select officername, month(tourstartdate) tsm, value from tours) src
pivot 
(sum(value) for tsm in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) p
```